# Using Boost::odeint with Eigen::Matrix as state vector--edit

Tags: c++, boost, eigen

I have a question very simmilar to this:
[Using Boost::odeint with Eigen::Matrix as state vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782224/using-boostodeint-with-eigenmatrix-as-state-vector?answertab=active#tab-top)
.
But instead of using a constant stepper i want to use a controlled stepper. Therefore I changend the code from the nicely working:

```
typedef runge_kutta_dopri5<state_type,double,state_type,double,vector_space_algebra> error_stepper_type;
integrate_const(  error_stepper_type()  ,  odefunction,X0 , 0 , 10,  dt));
```

to

```
typedef runge_kutta_dopri5<state_type,double,state_type,double,vector_space_algebra> error_stepper_type;
typedef controlled_runge_kutta< error_stepper_type > controlled_stepper_type;
double abs_err = 1.0e-10 , rel_err = 1.0e-6 , a_x = 1.0 , a_dxdt = 1.0;
controlled_stepper_type controlled_stepper( default_error_checker< double,vector_space_algebra >( abs_err , rel_err , a_x , a_dxdt ) );
integrate_adaptive( controlled_stepper ,  odefunction, X0 , 0.0 , 10.0 ,dt );
```

and again getting compiler errors concerning the vector_space_algebra.
 Is there a solution as easy as for the constant stepper?