# Eigen Vectors as ODEINT integrate parameters

Tags: c++, boost, eigen, odeint

I am trying to port the Harmonic Oscillator tutorial from ODEINT to Eigen, so that I could use `VectorXd` for state vectors. I cannot, however, make it compile.

I've been following [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782224/using-boostodeint-with-eigenmatrix-as-state-vector) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008302/eigen-vector3d-as-state-vector-with-odeints-symplectic-rkn-sb3a-mclachlan), for instance [this is the closest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35656237/dynamic-eigen-vectors-in-boostodeint) except that I don't use any stepper here.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

typedef Eigen::VectorXd state_type;
// was vector<double>

const double gam = 0.15;

/* The rhs of x' = f(x) defined as a class */
class harm_osc
{

public:

    void operator() ( const state_type &x , state_type &dxdt , const double /* t */ )
    {
        dxdt(0) =  x(1);
        dxdt(1) = -x(0) - gam*x(1);
//        dxdt[0] = x[1];
//        dxdt[1] = -x[0] - gam*x[1];
    }
};
/* The rhs of x' = f(x) */
void harmonic_oscillator(const state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, const double /* t */ )
{
    dxdt(0) =  x(1);
    dxdt(1) = -x(0) - gam*x(1);
//    dxdt[0] = x[1];
//    dxdt[1] = -x[0] - gam*x[1];
}

void printer(const state_type &x , const double t)
{
//    std::cout << t << "," << x[0] << "," << x[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << t << "," << x(0) << "," << x(1) << std::endl;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    state_type x(2);
    x(0) = 1.0;
    x(1) = 0.0;
//    x[0] = 1.0;
//    x[1] = 0.0;

    std::cout << ">>>> FUNCTION" << std::endl;
//    boost::numeric::odeint::integrate(harmonic_oscillator, x, 0.0, 10.0, 0.1, printer);
//    boost::numeric::odeint::runge_kutta4<state_type, double, state_type, double, boost::numeric::odeint::vector_space_algebra> stepper();
    boost::numeric::odeint::integrate<double, decltype(harmonic_oscillator), state_type, double, decltype(printer)>(harmonic_oscillator, x, 0.0, 10.0, 0.1, printer);

    std::cout << ">>>> CLASS" << std::endl;
    x(0) = 1.0;
    x(1) = 0.0;
//    x[0] = 1.0;
//    x[1] = 0.0;
    harm_osc ho;
    boost::numeric::odeint::integrate<double, decltype(harmonic_oscillator), state_type, double, decltype(printer)>(ho, x, 0.0, 10.0, 0.1, printer);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains about `No matching function for call to 'begin'` in `range_algebra.hpp` from ODEINT in both class and function versions of `integrate`. As a matter of fact, Eigen matrices have no `begin`/`end`.

I've tried to play with the template parameters (as you see) with no avail.

Any hint?

## Assertion failed using Eigen from repo

Using the latest Eigen from the repo (not the latest stable version), I can, as suggested, compile it and run. However, it **fails an assertion** in the `integrate` call tree:

```
Assertion failed: (index >= 0 && index < size()), function operator(), file eigen/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h, line 427.
```

The call that fails is `dxdt(0) = x(1);` and subsequently in `DenseCoeffsBase.h`:

```
    EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE Scalar&
    operator()(Index index)
    {
      eigen_assert(index >= 0 && index < size()); // <---- INDEX IS 0, SIZE IS 0
      return coeffRef(index);
    }
```

Is it possible that ODEINT is trying to default-construct a `VectorXd`? I followed the path to my ODE call and `dxdt` is actually `NULL`:

```
(lldb) e dxdt
(state_type) $1 = {
  Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > = {
    m_storage = {
      m_data = 0x0000000000000000
      m_rows = 0
    }
  }
}
```

What is worse is that when using `resizeLike` to allow resizing `dxdt`, in the second step (so the first real computation of `integrate`) I have a `x` with `NULL` values:

```
(lldb) e dxdt
(state_type) $0 = {
  Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > = {
    m_storage = {
      m_data = 0x0000000000000000
      m_rows = 0
    }
  }
}
(lldb) e x
(state_type) $1 = {
  Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > = {
    m_storage = {
      m_data = 0x0000000000000000
      m_rows = 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try the master branch of Eigen, `begin()`/`end()` have been introduced a while ago.

Comment: And N.B. `dxdt[0] = x[1];` etc, works for Eigen vector types (not for matrices, though), so no need to rewrite these lines.

Comment: The requirements for `boost::odeint` StateType are described in detail [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost_numeric_odeint/odeint_in_detail/state_types__algebras_and_operations.html); TL;DR: for non-fixed size types, apart from providing `begin()` and `end()` your type must also support `boost::size( x )` and `x.resize( boost::size( y ) )`

Comment: Mmmh... so my choices are using a non-stable branch, or if I can, make a wrapper? @chtz do you have any info on why were begin/end excluded in the release?

Comment: It just has been a while since the last release -- that's mostly a time issue of the maintainers. You can of course write a wrapper, which just returns `this->data()` for `.begin()` and `this->data()+this->size()` for `end()` (plus const/non-const variants and some typedefs)

Comment: @chtz I've updated the question. Now it compiles but Eigen crashes with an ominous zero size of the vector.

Comment: If this fails in your code, you could just `dxdt.resize(2)` (not sure why it would work with `std::vector` but not with `Eigen::VectorXd` in that case. But actually, if the size is known at compiletime to be 2, just use `Eigen::Vector2d`.

Comment: @chtz unfortunately, I know just at runtime what vector space I'll be using.

Comment: Did you try `dxdt.resize(2)` or `dxdt.resizeLike(x)` before setting its members?

Comment: @chtz interestingly, in the second step I have both `x` and `dxdt` invalid, and the assertion fires again. I've updated the question. That's weird. On other questions seemed that it should work out of the box...

Comment: Yea, no idea what happens inside odeint. And I don't want to debug that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that ODEINT **actually works fine with Eigen**... only it is **not documented**, as far as I can see.

Digging around ODEINT's code, I have found a promising `eigen.hpp` header deep in the `external` directory.

And lo and behold, it works flawlessly:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/numeric/odeint/external/eigen/eigen.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>

#define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
#include "fmt/core.h"
#include "fmt/format.h"
#include "fmt/format-inl.h"
#include "fmt/printf.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Eigen::VectorXd v;

    v.resize(2);

    typedef Eigen::VectorXd state_type;

    const double gam = 0.15;

    v(0) = 1.0;
    v(1) = 1.1;

    auto harmonic_oscillator = [&](const state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, const double t)
    {
        dxdt[0] = x[1];
        dxdt[1] = -x[0] - gam*x[1];
    };

    auto printer = [&](const state_type &x, const double t)
    {
        fmt::print(out, "time: {} state: {}\n", t, x);
    };

    odeint::integrate(harmonic_oscillator, v, 0.0 , 10.0 , 0.01, printer);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps others.